# Cómo guardar valor de un Promise

Tags: javascript, promesas

Aquí tengo el codigo:

```
function request(data) {
...
    var result;
    var req = fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json()).then(function(dat) {
        result = dat[0][0][0];
    return result;
})

r = request("...")
// Aqui ^ obtengo "undefined"
```

Lo que quiero es guardar el valor `dat[0][0][0]` y luego retornarlo, para usarlo otra vez.
¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deberías hacer es usar la logica de lo que quieres hacer dentro de la función, ya que como estas usando .then el valor solo va a existir dentro de este. Es por ello te sale undefined cuando llamas la función:

```
    function request(data) {
    ...
        var result;
        var req = fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json()).then(function(dat) {

        //tu codigo aquí en lugar de retornar

        })
    }
```

Me pasaba lo mismo y de esta manera lo solucioné.

Comment: lo que pasa es que allí se acaba la función, entonces tendría que hacer todo dentro del then?

Comment: solo quería obtener un valor de un request que quiero hacer, para usarlo en discord.js

Comment: encontré un enlace haciendo referencia a lo que quieres https://medium.com/angular-bolivia/c%C3%B3digo-as%C3%ADncrono-en-javascript-27f82a3c94e5 no lo he probado, pero dale un vistazo a la parte que dice 'Promesas' y pruebas si te sirve. Parece ser una buena solución

Comment: gracias ahora lo modifiqué un poco y lo conseguí

Answer (score 0):

Debe hacerse una combinación entre async y await.

En la función que tienes `request()`, deberías devolver la promesa de **fetch** y adicionar la palabra reservada **async** en la definición de este.

```
async function request(data) {
    // ...
    return fetch(url)
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(function(dat) {
        result = dat[0][0][0];
        return result;
    })
}
```

[He aquí una página que muestra usos con ejemplos](https://javascript.info/async-await)

**EDIT:**
Para hacer uso del await, se debe usar dentro de una función async, así que tienes dos opciones.

1. Usar el valor retornado en el mismo método request
2. Obtener el valor retornado en otra función async así:

```
// para el caso 1 dentro el método request sin hacer el return
async function request(data) {
  // ...
  let r = await fetch(url)
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(function(dat) {
      result = dat[0][0][0];
      return result;
    })
}

// para el caso 2 dejas el método request con el asnyc y el return
async function request(data) {
    // ...
    return fetch(url)
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(function(dat) {
        result = dat[0][0][0];
        return result;
    })
}

// en otro método async utilizas el await
async function otraFuncion() {
    let r = await request("...");
}
```

Comment: También lo hice con async y await, o sea, también me sirvió tu respuesta:)